# Why don't capacitor's plates stick together?

Tags: capacitor, vibration

When capacitor plates carry opposite charges, then why don't they stick together due to attraction? They must stick since the plates have opposite charges.

Comment: Please do not type messages in all capitals, it is experienced as yelling to people reading it.

Comment: @jippie IMO, it's more of an aesthetic issue. ALL CAPS JUST LOOKS BAD!

Comment: Might be interesting to make up an air-gap capacitor from kitchen aluminum foil to experiment with, perhaps hanging two sheets adjacent to each other and supported at the top edge only.  But be sure to use low-voltage overcurrent- protected supplies, and megaohm series resistors, both for your own safety and because you'll likely short out the device if the experiment is a "success".  You could try a sheet of plastic in between to mitigate the shorting, but don't rely on it.

Answer (score 7):

As you say, capacitor plates experience attraction due to the opposite charge. However this typically cannot be seen from the outside. The "plates" press against the insulating dielectric that separates them.

In rare situations one can hear the mechanical effects of the rapid release of the charge from the capacitor: the capacitor makes an audible "clack" when the charge is released instantly - i.e. through an almost short circuit.

This is a common occurrence with for example high-power pulsed laser power supplies: Such a power supply stores high-voltage energy in a bank of large capacitors for a period of e.g. 1/10th of a second. All the stored energy is then released in about one billionth of a second. This is accompanied with a fairly noisy "clack" that originates from the release of mechanical stress in the storage capacitors. - With large laser systems the discharge noise is so loud that ear-protection has to be worn in the vicinity of the power supply.

Comment: Could this acoustic effect be caused by magnetic effect of high current pulse, rather than decomression of dielectric ?

Comment: @RocketSurgeon To be perfectly honest, I have not personally investigated this effect but accepted the explanation of the service person for the laser I was working with. I cannot guarantee this to be correct or even that no other effects contribute to the noise I mentioned. - Maybe somebody else here can shed more light on the issue.

Answer (score 5):

The plates attract each other, but the force is weak compared to the the (mechanical) construction.

Answer (score 2):

There is no clarification what kind of capacitor you are referring. But most of capacitor plates are fixed mechanically or if you are referring to electrolytic capacitors then they have insulators placed in between. Also magnetic charges & electrical charges are different.